# js - filters in fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, fetch

I have a problem. I'm trying to fetch an API, but theres an error-message which says:
At least one filtering parameter must exist

I found something on google, but nothing of it worked.
My code looks like this:

```js
let api = await fetch("https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/#2Q8GRY8LQ", {
  method: `GET`,
  headers: new Headers({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_TOKEN}`,
  })
})
let apiJSON = await api.json()
console.log(apiJSON)
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider reading through their documentation? https://developer.clashofclans.com/?ref=apilist.fun#/login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `encodeURIComponent` of the clan tag like this:

```
let api = await fetch(`https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/${encodeURIComponent("#2Q8GRY8LQ")}`, {
    method: `GET`,
    headers: new Headers({
       'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_TOKEN}`,
    })
})
let apiJSON = await api.json()
console.log(apiJSON)
```